# Why aren't the peer-to-peer connections transitive?

Tags: private-blockchain, connections, peers

In a private blockchain network, if there are three nodes - A, B, and C

`A` is connected to `B`

`B` is connected to `C`

But, why is `A` not connected to `C`?

Wouldn't that make the connections and ultimately the network more reliable?

Comment: I think if it so every peer will be connected to all the other peers. in this case we will have a DDOS risk and more bandwidth consumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all `N` nodes connected to all `N-1` others, that would require a lot of bandwidth and work managing all these connections. There is a whole field of research dedicated to optimal connections distribution given a desired "network diameter".

Not to forget that certain network topologies, think NAT and port-forwarding, do not allow all nodes to connect to each other.